# How to remove an object of an array in javascript by checking checkbox

Tags: javascript

I have two inputs by type checkbox :

```
<input type="checkbox" value="5da1dc651d011c56ef1cb3db_693715" onchange="handleChange(this)">
<input type="checkbox" value="6da1dc651d011c56ef1cb3db_837154" onchange="handleChange(this)">
```

I want to make an array of value of input when it will be checked and when checked is false the object that has that value will be removed , but it would not be removed

```
    var Array = [];
     var obj = {};
    function handleChange(elem) {
    var check = $(elem).prop("checked");
    if (check == true) {
        obj["obj"] = $(elem).val();
        optionalservices.push(obj)
      } else if (check == false) {
        optionalservices = optionalservices.filter(function (item) {
            return item.obj !== $(elem).val();
        })
     }
    }
```

Comment: Please note that `Array` with uppercase A is a JavaScript type and using it as variable name is confusing, try to find another, appropriate name.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:-

```
let selectedValuesArr = [];
function handleChange(event) {
    const isChecked = event.target.checked;
    if(isChecked) {
        selectedValuesArr.push(event.target.value);
    } else {
        selectedValuesArr.splice(selectedValuesArr.indexOf(event.target.value), 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.map()` only on the checked check boxes with `.get()`

```js
function handleChange() {
  var check = $(':checked').map((i, c) => ({sid: c.value})).get();
  console.log(check);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="5da1dc651d011c56ef1cb3db_693715" onchange="handleChange()">
<input type="checkbox" value="6da1dc651d011c56ef1cb3db_837154" onchange="handleChange()">
```

Comment: Thanks @Mamun for your answer but my Array is going to be like this :

Comment: [

    { "sid" : "5da1dc651d011c56ef1cb3db_693715"},{ "sid" : "5da1dc651d011c56ef1cb3d1_693715"}]

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this with little more Optimization

```
let selectedValuesArr = [];
function handleChange(elem) {
  elem.checked ? selectedValuesArr.push(elem.value) : selectedValuesArr.splice(selectedValuesArr.indexOf(elem.value), 1);
}
```